# Matlab: Assign weights to angle mesh values to get an Isotropic Field

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D spatial field of dimensions MxN with angle values (0-360 degs) in each node (x_i,y_j). In Matlab I trace the trajectory of a particule starting at (StartX,StartY) through the fild with the command streamline:

```
streamline(X,Y,u,v,Start_xi,Start_yi)
```

where u, v are the angle components. My question is: I want to assign probabilistic weights to each node, so that streamline shows preference to those nodes with the largest weight, regardless of the angle value. It could be interpreted as providing some sort of isotropy to the mesh.

Any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a weighting mechanism, but you could possibly trick it into getting double weight for a point by duplicating that point.

Comment: Interesting thanks!, how the duplication could be implemented?